# what happens when a function with static variable called by multiple thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Suppose there is a function :

```
Obj* Obj::instance()
{
   static Obj obj;
   return &obj;
}
```

As we known that obj will be initialized when Obj::instance has been called for the first time.
But what will happen if multiple thread call this function concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

Thread with the highest priority gets a lock on that variable!